# Recurrence Function

Tags: recurrence-relations

I found them in a test but just able to solve and there are no answers announced, so please check my answer for

$$I(2,n)\ ,\ I(3,n)\ ,\ I(5,3)$$ given $$I(m,1) =I(1,n) =1\ and\ I (m+1,n) +I (m,n+1) =I (m+1,n+1)$$

These are my answer
$$I(2,n) = {n}$$
$$I(3,n) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1$$
$$I(5,3) = 15$$

Comment: Based on my calculation, $I(2,n) = n$, $I(3,n) = \sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, $I(5,3)=15$.

Comment: Note the symmetry in $m$ and $n$ - you should have $I(5,3)=I(3,5)$

Comment: I just commented my solution for $$I(3,n)$$, please check it.

Answer (score 1):

$$I(m,n) = \binom {n+m-2}{n-1} = \frac {(n+m-2)!}{(n-1)!(m-1)!},$$ so the first and the third answers are correct while the second is not. $I(3,n)=\frac {n(n+1)} 2$.

Comment: $$I(3,n) = I(3,n-1) + I(2,n)\ (and\ I(2,n)=n)$$
Then it continues this pattern
$$I(3,n) = I(3,n-2) + n-1$$
$$I(3,n) = I(3,n-3) + n-2$$
and I got
$$I(3,n) = I(3,n-(n-1)) + n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ...+ n-(n-1)$$
$$I(3,n) = I(3,1) + \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

what is my mistake?

Comment: There are some mistype in 3rd and 4th lines
For 3rd, $$I(3,n-1)\ not\ I(3,n)$$
and 4th is $$I(3,n-2)\ not\ I(3,n)$$

Comment: Mistake is here: $I(3,n) = I(3,n-(n-1)) + n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ...+ n-(n-1)$. It must be $I(3,n) = I(3,n-(n-1)) + n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ...+ n-(n-2)$.